# The title 君主 kunshu as applied to the shogun

Tags: titles

There are a few occurrences of this in the early contacts with the West (eg the 1854 Treaty of Kanagawa and some other places) but I find virtually no discussion of this usage in the literature (apart from a brief mention in a 1991 article by De Palma in Italian).   Moreover, in foreign language versions of the documents where it occurs the word is rendered as Emperor or Sovereign.  There is extensive discussion of the frequent title Taikun as well as the rarer title King of Japan for the shogun, but I can't find anything on kunshu.  I don't need basic information about this word.  I need specifically references to scholarly discussions of its use--or any occurrences of it being used like this before 1850 or so.  Thank you very much.

Comment: [This wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%9B%E4%B8%BB%E5%8F%B7#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC) suggests that it was never used as a title.

Answer (score 1):

君主/monarch is an umbrella term that includes 国王 (king), 天皇 (Japanese emperor), 皇帝 (emperor), and so on. Since it's an umbrella term, individual monarchs are not directly called 君主 by the people. The "Japanese 君主" always refers to the 天皇/Emperor. (This does not mean that the Japanese 天皇 was actually called 君主 by the people at any point in history.)

Technically, the word 将軍/Shogun is a **military** position meaning "general". It's a word that represents the head of all soldiers (or samurai). Although the 将軍 was the *de facto* hereditary ruler of Japan in the Edo period, his position was (nominally) appointed by the emperor. Therefore, my understanding is that 将軍 is never classified as a type of 君主.

Comment: Thank but the reason I asked the question as I did was to avoid wasting YOUR time looking things up in places where you will not find the answer.  And both YOURS and MINE by you telling me things everyone (even me) knows.  The word is used as I said, and the q is whether anyone can find any discussion of it in the literature besides the one article I located.    If you were minded to help, this could yield something interesting.  There is f.ex. some confusion about the RATIFICATION document.  Also there are supposed to exist Dutch and Chinese versions of the 1854 treaty which I cannot find.

Comment: @AttilathePun "Things everyone (even me) knows"? Does that "everyone" include ordinary Japanese speakers? Maybe you're thinking this is a members-only forum for history experts? What I wrote is already a relatively advanced topic about 君主 from an ordinary speaker's standpoint (they don't know the "basic" definition of 君主). If you already know 君主 is a wrong word to refer to 将軍, you at least need to clearly explain why you are asking a tricky question like this. There are a few people on this site who have expert-level knowledge of Japanese history, so if you're lucky you might get an answer.

Comment: Oy. What I mean is that looking things up in a dictionary or in wikipedia is not what I asked for, and on the other hand all people (NOT experts in J history, some of whom I have consulted and who know NOTHING) CAN help.  What I would ask you or anyone else who knows the language better than I do and is willing to help is to do what I cannot because my J is not great, i.e., simply see whether there are any published articles or books that discuss this topic, first, and second if someone were willing to help me look over the ratification document which is in wikipedia.  Thank you very much

Comment: From your statements so far, you are, for some reason, asking about a narrow topic that is far more advanced than Wikipedia and that even history experts may have to spend a lot of time researching. I can't help you since I personally don't have the ability to search ancient documents, but you should at least explain to others **why** you need such information. On Stack Exchange, there are many experts who are willing to share their knowledge for free, but even such people can't help you without understanding why you need their help.